# Passing a variable by reference to another class

Tags: c++, class, reference

I'm trying to pass a variable by reference to a different class, but I cannot get it to work.

I have some config object that I create in the main application, then when I run the config dialog, I want to provide this config object to the dialog.

This is what I have so far:

**ConfigDialog.h**:

```
class ConfigDialog {

public:
    explicit ConfigDialog(kimai::Config& config, QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    kimai::Config& config_;
};
```

**ConfigDialog.cpp**:

```
ConfigDialog::ConfigDialog(kimai::Config& config, QWidget *parent) {        
    config_ = config;
    // Do something with config_ - get/set values, etc.
}
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
ConfigDialog.cpp:7: error: C2758: 'ConfigDialog::config_' : must be initialized in constructor base/member initializer list
```

Any idea how to fix this issue?

(I tried adding `config_ = config` to the initialization list but this is not valid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot initialize a reference by assignment, it needs to be done in the initializer list:

```
ConfigDialog::ConfigDialog(kimai::Config& config, QWidget *parent) : config_(config) {        
    // Do something with config_ - get/set values, etc.
}
```

The `config_ = config` assignment is a call of the assignment operator on the value being referenced by `config` into the variable being referenced by `config_`, which is uninitialized. Assignment syntax works only when it is combined with the declaration:

```
int y = 5;
int &x = y;    // This works
int &z; z = y; // This does not work!
int w = 4;
x = y;         // This is an assignment to y through a reference
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use initializer list to initialize a reference:

```
ConfigDialog::ConfigDialog(kimai::Config& config, QWidget *parent) 
        : config_(config)
{        
    // Do something with config_ - get/set values, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a constructor initializer list:

```
ConfigDialog::ConfigDialog(kimai::Config& config, QWidget *parent)
    : config_(config)
{
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't `config_(config)` create a copy of `config`?

Comment: @Laurent No, it just copies the _reference_ which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Error message told you everything. Try this:

```
ConfigDialog::ConfigDialog(kimai::Config& config, QWidget *parent) 
   :config_(config)
{           
    // Do something with config_ - get/set values, etc.
}
```

Class members of reference type must be initialized in the [initialization lists](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6).

Answer (score 0):

You should add it to the initialization list using constructor syntax:

```
ConfigDialog::ConfigDialog(kimai::Config& config, QWidget *parent)
    : config_ (config)
{        
    // Do something with config_ - get/set values, etc.
}
```